# Supabase JS: Best way to resubscribe to realtime database channel after it’s closed?

Tags: supabase, supabase-js

I’m using supabase-js with a React app, implementing its realtime functionality to get real-time updates from the database in the UI. Overall it’s working great. Sometimes, though, the realtime channels will close (they stop working and I get a `CLOSED` event).

When that happens, I’d like to reopen them. Before I do, though, I’m not sure if I should first unsubscribe from the closed channel (`supabase.removeChannel()`). I’d assumed yes, but when I do that I get another `CLOSED` event on the old channel, which makes me wonder if the `removeChannel()` call is unnecessary (or even harmful).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should do `removeChannel` otherwise you'll end up opening a bunch of connections. Getting the `CLOSED` message after that is expected.